# Is there a way to set a context variable's value within js or html when using Django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I'm working on a website using python django as a back end, and am currently trying to pull values from a HTML form and pass it to a django form. This is due to only certain fields needing access to data from the database and needing JS on the page to show/hide based on the values of certain selects in the HTML. What I need to do is to set the value of an object's attribute that is passed in from the views.py

```
 <script>
 output = document.getElementById("example");
 {{ form.fieldImChanging.value }} = output.value;
 </script>
 ...
 <form action="" method="POST" class="row gy-2 gx-3 align-items-center">
 <label for="example">TestField</label>
 <input type="text" name="example" maxlength="16" size=20 required="">
 ...
 <input class="btn btn-success col-3 mt-2" type="submit" value="Submit">
 <a href="{% url '*snipped url*' *snipped vars* %}" class="btn btn-secondary col-3 mt-2">Back</a>
 </form>
```

Where the trouble lies is in getting that context variable to set, because as of right now that will just create a variable named after whatever the default value of fieldImChanging is in the django form. Is there a way to do this with django at all?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understsood correctly but It looks like something Ajax could solve. I've used It in a project to create a Dynamic dropdown inside a form, the previous entries served as values to the other queries